# React router v4 asynchronous route handling

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Consider the following two routes

```
<Route path="/:username" component={Profile} />
<Route path="*" component={NotFound} />
```

I'm aware the path `/:username` would always match even for a user that does not exist so I am trying the following

```
<Route
  path="/:username"
  render={({ match }) => {
    return userExists(match.params.username) ?
      <Profile match={match} /> : <NotFound match={match} />;
  }}
/>
```

`userExists()` being a function that returns `true` or `false` after making a call to the database to check if the user with the given username exists.

Am I handling this in the completely wrong way? It feels funny to have such a function in my route handler.

Comment: I think this question is primarily opinion based, but here's my opinion - you're router is fine. If you want to create another abstraction that executes the ternery over there instead of here in the router you might have a cleaner route tag but seriously who cares that's a low utility abstraction.

Comment: *"userExists() being a function that returns true or false after making a call to the database"* Is it asynchronous? (Your title suggests it is, your code suggests it isn't.) If so, you can't synchronously use its return value like that.

Answer (score 0):

It's not wrong.  What you are essentially doing is rendering a stateless functional component:  https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/components-and-props.html#functional-and-class-components

It depends on the overall structure and needs of your app whether or not this functional component should be defined in a separate file, but it's perfectly fine to conditionally return React elements in functional components.

To further illustrate the symmetry between functions and Components in React, consider the alternative approach in which you pass a function as the "component" param: (note the use of implicit return with arrow functions)

```
<Route
  path="/:username"
  component={({ match }) => userExists(match.params.username) ?
      <Profile match={match} /> : <NotFound match={match} />
  }}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `userExists` is defined to be asynchronous, I don't see how the code is "correct" at all, that is, I don't think it will work, and I don't think the original question has yet been solved.